# Angular 2: ngFor first of type without attribute

Tags: angular

i try to build a ngFor loop and want to add a class to the first element without a attribute.

This is what i got so far:

```
<div *ngFor="let workout of myProgramm.trainingSchedule[myProgramm.currentWeek]; let i = index;"
             (click)="goToWorkoutDetailPage(i)"
             class="my-workout-item {{workout.workout_done ? 'is-done': ''}}">
            .....
        </div>
```

In this example i want to add a class to the first element of the list which dont have the attribute "workout_done".

Is this possible?

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `*ngFor` alone. There is no way to refer other items in `*ngFor`.

It would be better to find the first element that doesn't have `workout_done`, assign it to a property `firstUndoneWorkout` in the class and then use

```
    <div *ngFor="let workout of myProgramm.trainingSchedule[myProgramm.currentWeek]; let i = index;"
         (click)="goToWorkoutDetailPage(i)"
         class="my-workout-item" [class.workout_done]="workout == firstUndoneWorkout">
        .....
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, the correct way to do this is:

`[class.is-done]="workout.workout_done"`

and if you're looking to do it with one that doesn't have workout_done just check the opposite.

Here's the template syntax documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass